# iPhone OpenCv build issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, build, opencv

I'm trying to build open_cv on the iphone. I'm a pre-compiled version of it from http://github.com/niw/iphone_opencv_test and am seeing the following build errors...

```
 "_cvCvtColor", referenced from:


      +[PFFaceDetection CreateIplImageFromUIImage:] in PFFaceDetection.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFImageEffects", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref-to-PFImageEffects in PFEditorViewController.o


  "_cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade", referenced from:


      +[PFFaceDetection detectFacesWithImage:] in PFFaceDetection.o


  "_cvHaarDetectObjects", referenced from:


      +[PFFaceDetection detectFacesWithImage:] in PFFaceDetection.o


  "_cvReleaseMemStorage", referenced from:


      +[PFFaceDetection detectFacesWithImage:] in PFFaceDetection.o


  "_cvCreateImage", referenced from:


      +[PFFaceDetection CreateIplImageFromUIImage:] in PFFaceDetection.o


      +[PFFaceDetection CreateIplImageFromUIImage:] in PFFaceDetection.o


      -[UIImage(OpenCV) cvGrayscaleImage] in UIImageOpenCV.o


      -[UIImage(OpenCV) cvImage] in UIImageOpenCV.o


  "_cvEqualizeHist", referenced from:


      +[PFFaceDetection detectFacesWithImage:] in PFFaceDetection.o


  "_cvLoad", referenced from:


      +[PFFaceDetection detectFacesWithImage:] in PFFaceDetection.o


  "_cvCreateMemStorage", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't link proper OpenCV libraries into your project. Example project uses different library paths depending on the current selected architecture. Instead, it is possible to rename simulator versions and drag all four files into Xcode project.